# Smart European Date input control

Tags: orbeon

Using orbeon-4.1.0.201304182144-PE, I'm having a problem with Smart Date completion.

I've included the configuration property:

```
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.xforms.format.input.date"  value="[D]/[M]/[Y]"/>
```

to take European-style dates as input.

The condition for Smart Date completion:

> When the oxf.xforms.format.input.date property starts with [D: e.g.
>   20/10

from [Input Control-Forms](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-controls/input-control#TOC-date-time-and-dateTime-types) doesn't seem to trigger. I get:

```
Input    Output
20       20/5/2013       (Correct)
20/5     Not Valid       (Incorrect, should be 20/5/2013)
20/5/13  20/5/2013       (Correct)
5/20     20/5/2013       (Incorrect, should be Not Valid)
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: Nice catch! I am surprised that this bug could stay around for so long, as this code has been around for a while. Anyhow, as mentioned in me response below, this is now fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a [bug](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/998), and it is now fixed. The fix will be in the next release of Orbeon Forms, which at the time of this writing will most likely be 4.2.